# How to detect if the driving direction between two points is unavailable

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm using the Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager API to calculate route directions between two points. Suppose no directions are available between two co-ordinates I want to alert to the user. How do I detect that no route was found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directionsError event. This event will fire when it can't calculate directions between two locations. You can try this out here: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#DirectionsModule15

Comment: Thanks for that. Another thing i want to do is keep the waypoints intact even if there is no route between them which dosent happpen. Is there any solution for that.

Comment: The waypoints should stay in the directions manager but won't render a route. You could always have it fall back to showing the waypoints as pushpins to indicate it's not routable, if the route calculation fails. Or showing the failed waypoints as pushpins, remove them from the directions manager and then calculate and display the directions.